# Opening an external html page from my Navbar using WayPoints js

Tags: javascript, jquery, navbar, smooth-scrolling, jquery-waypoints

I have  a navbar with links to divs in my html page. One of the links however is an external html page. Clicking the link to the html page doesn't work and I can't figure out why. In my waypoints function, I have something like this:

```
$('#home, login.html, #about, designs, #services, #contact').waypoint(function() {
    activenav($(this));
}, { offset: function() {
    return -$(this).height()+52;
  }});
$('#home, login.html, #about, designs, #services, #contact').waypoint(function() {
    activenav($(this));
}, { offset: '51px' });
```

This is my navbar:

```
<nav>
        <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.html" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#designs">Interior Designs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">Our Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you're misusing the jQuery `$('')` selector syntax. If you'd like to get the list of elements by their hrefs, you need to to this: `$('[href="value_of_href"]')`

Comment: So what do I need to do in-order assign the value of hrefs to my selector? For example, the login.html?

Comment: `$('a[href="login.html"]')` will select the `<a href="login.html" ...` element

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misusing the [jQuery $('') selector syntax](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). You need to select the elements by the [value of their href attribute](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) like this this:

```
$('[href="value_of_href"]')
```